# connect Google Cloud Run services with VCP and get 403

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

I have 2 services, **frontend** and **backend**, deployed on **Google Cloud Run**.

I want to allow only frontend to send request to backend so I set backend ingress to `allow internal traffic only`.

Then, I set up **serverless VPC access** with [this guides](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access?hl=en#create-connector).

Both services now connect to the same VPC connector. Frontend egress is set to `Route all traffic through the VPC connector` and backend egress is set to `Route only requests to private IPs through the VPC connector`.

But when I send request from frontend to backend, it show [**CORS**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCHat.png) [**preflight 403 error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20Nzg.png).

I try to add permission to the backend service using frontend service account and set role to `Cloud Run Invoker` but still got 403

Comment: Ask yourselves: from where the requests to the backend are emitted? From the Front End service? Or from the user browser? When you know the request origin, you will understand your issue ;)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Well, the request comes from frontend service but the CORS such as access-control-allow-origin come from the browser, right? When I test in localhost, the preflight request can be done normally whether it is pass or not. So, when it show that preflight is forbidden, I assume that it come from authenticated of the Cloud Run. Am I understand right?

Comment: Your frontend serves static Javascript content, the javascript is interpreted and runs on the user browser. So, when a request is sent to the backend, the request comes from the internet, and not from the Cloud Run front end service. Therefore, the serverless VPC connector is useless, and your configuration "internal only" for the backend makes it unreachable from the internet (your user browser)

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Ok. I understand like this, the one that send the request is the client browser not frontend service in Cloud Run, so the request is not pass through VPC and because I set backend service as internal only, then, it show 403. If this is correct, then what method should I use to prevent public from access my backend API? I want to let only request come from frontend service.

Comment: Currently, I can think about setting origin config in backend service to specify the frontend domain but I'm not sure is this a good practice?

Comment: You can protect your backend with an API management platform. API Gateway or Apigee on Google Cloud. If your users are authenticated, it's easier. If not, I also recommend to use a load balancer with Cloud Armor to prevent attacks and OWASP issues.